A question "became hot network question" 32 times in a row, all within 28 seconds
The question How can I write a std::apply on a std::expected? has become a Hot Network Question. That's fine, there's nothing wrong with it being a hot question. The fact that it is a Hot Network Question doesn't need manual adjustment.
However, there are 32 "became hot network question" entries in the question's timeline and edit history, all with timestamps between 2024-07-11 18:27:26Z and 2024-07-11 18:27:54Z. So, while the end result of the question being a Hot Network Question is fine, something went wrong with the process to end up with 32 entries in the question's history/timeline.

Question clearly has no chill....

maybe they asked for it to be extra spicy?

Probably related on MSE: Very hot network questions found

When you're hot you're hot.
